# 404 Not Found error in preflight OPTIONS when executing a PUT method in CakePHP API with axios in React App

Tags: reactjs, apache, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, we have an API with CakePHP 3.7. We are using `resources` to generate CRUD methods. The API is hosted in a server with apache2 and is accessed through a manager app using React (this app is a microservice). The manager makes the calls through `axios` and is correctly managing the GET, POST and HEAD requests (simple CORS requests) but we're having problems when it comes to more complex requests such as PUT or DELETE.

When executing PUT or DELETE requests it makes a preflight OPTIONS request and it returns a 404 Not Found error. And some messages in console related with CORS which are:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSPreflightDidNotSucceed?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default

We already tried several fixes, such as using [CakePHP CORS plugin](https://github.com/ozee31/cakephp-cors), adding CORS Headers in the response in the beforeRender and beforeFilter methods of AppController and also adding CORS headers in the apache, none of this seams to be working.

```php
    private function setCorsHeaders() {
        $this->response->cors($this->request)
            ->allowOrigin(['*'])
            ->allowMethods(['*'])
            ->exposeHeaders(['X-Total-Pages'])
            ->maxAge(800)
            ->build();
    }

    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        $this->setCorsHeaders();
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        if($this->request->is('options')) {
            $this->setCorsHeaders();
            return $this->response;
        }
    }
```

```
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "X-Total-Pages"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"
```

The expected behaviour is that the PUT and DELETE methods are executed properly (the preflight OPTIONS should pass successfully). Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP >=3.4, `Http\Response` objects are [treated as immutable](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-cross-origin-request-headers-cors) by many methods. The method chain called on [`$this->request->cors()`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Http.Response.html#_cors) uses the [`CorsBuilder`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Http.CorsBuilder.html#_build) class to queue the desired headers on an immutable response which is returned when calling `build()`.

Try assigning the return from `CorsBuilder::build()` with the queued headers to `$this->response`.

```
    private function setCorsHeaders() {
        $this->response = $this->response->cors($this->request)
            ->allowOrigin(['*'])
            ->allowMethods(['*'])
            ->exposeHeaders(['X-Total-Pages'])
            ->maxAge(800)
            ->build();
    }
```

Comment: That's it, thank you. I also added `allowHeaders(['Content-Type])` beacause CORS was also complaining about it.